# Scroll to anchor on pseudo-framed site hides the header

Tags: html, css

**tl;dr**
I have an [HTML+CSS page layout](http://phrogz.net/tmp/framed.html) using positioned and scrolling boxes to simulate a framed layout. When I click on a link to a sub-page anchor, the entire page scrolls, hiding the header.

**Details:**
You can see the problem here: http://phrogz.net/tmp/framed.html

- When the browser window is tall enough that the side navigation does not overflow, clicking on a link correctly scrolls the 'contents' section to the header.
- However, when the browser window is so short that the side navigation shows a sidebar, **clicking on a link in the sidebar causes the entire `body` to scroll** so that the header is off the top of the screen. Chrome, FF, and IE9 all behave similarly.

The header, sidebar and contents are all absolutely positioned to fit within the viewport and have either `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto`. I also have `html, body { overflow:hidden }`.

How can I best fix this, so that navigating to an `#id` on the page never scrolls the body?

*I'm looking for a CSS/HTML solution; I know that I could use JavaScript hacks to 'fix' this, either by intercepting the click and scrolling the `#contents` through script as desired, or to use `document.body.scrollTop = 0` after the click occurs.*

---

Here's a summary of the markup:

**framed.html**

```html
<body>
  <article id="contents">
    <section id="section1">
      <header><h2>Section 1</h2></header>
      <!-- section 1 contents -->
    </section>
    <section id="section2">
      <header><h2>Section 2</h2></header>
      <!-- section 2 contents -->
    </section>
    <!-- more sections -->
  </article>
  <nav id="site-nav"><ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    <!-- more links -->
  </ul></nav>
  <header id="header"></header>
</body>
```

**framed.css**

```css
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
#header {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:50px;
}
#contents {
  overflow:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px; left:210px; right:0; bottom:0;
  padding:1em 1.5em 600px 1.5em;
}
#site-nav {
  overflow:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px; bottom:0; left:0; width:210px;
}
```

**Edit**: Fixed version of the document can be seen here: http://phrogz.net/tmp/framed-fixed.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not try position:fixed for the #header and the #site-nav?

Comment: Using `position:fixed` on all three portions (`#header`, `#contents` and `#site-nav`) does fix it. Feels a bit like a hack, but not bad at all. Thanks.

Comment: All we do is create hacks. But I don't look at this as an hack, it looks like the preferred method to get what you want :)

Comment: @einar What I find odd is that the problem only occurred when the side navigation was overflowing, yet the side navigation had `overflow:auto` and was positioned to the bottom of the window, and thus should never have been changing the height of the `body` (IMO).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not that sure why.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative fix (and further insight into the problem):

Removing the `600px` bottom padding from `#contents` fixes the problem. The same effect (having a great deal of blank space at the end of the document so that the last item can be linked to directly) can be achieved either via:

```css
#contents > *:last-child { margin-bottom:600px }
```

Or, using simpler CSS and a slight change in the markup:

```html
<article id="contents">
  <!-- full contents here -->
  <hr id="contents-end">
</article>
```

```css
#contents-end { visibility:hidden; margin-top:600px }
```

Comment: Credit goes to @somasin on Freenode #css IRC for discovering that the padding was related to the issue.